# Condition Makevars for Solaris

Tags: r, build, package, solaris

My R package is generating errors on Solaris because of long lines (i.e., greater than 80 character) in Fortran files. I was able to fix this problem on platforms using gnu compilers with the following line in my `Makevars` file:

```
PKG_FFLAGS=--fixed-line-length-132
```

In digging around, it seems that the Solaris Studio equivalent is `-e`, so this an easy fix if I can figure out how to make the `PKG_FFLAGS` variable conditional on the build platform.

The [R extensions manual shows an example of conditionally setting a variable on Windows](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars). Can anyone point me to the appropriate environment variables to use to do the equivalent for Solaris vs. other platforms?

I don't have a Solaris box to test on, and it would be nice to get this right before taking up more time from the CRAN gatekeepers.

Comment: I once used `vagrant` to easily setup a solaris VM and tested my package there.